# Работа со строками в Си. Как остановить разбиение строки

Tags: c

Строка вводится с клавиатуры. Нужно вывести слова, которые состоят только из латинских букв. Программа работает и выводит все правильно, но не могу понять как остановить разбор строки после обработки последнего слова. После обработки последнего слова программа вылетает. В отладчике выдает такую строку:

> Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
>   **token** было 0x1110112.

```
void outputWords(char *str, int str_len);

int main() {
char str[256];
gets_s(str);
outputWords(str, strlen(str));
return 0;
}

void outputWords(char *string, int str_len)
{
int cout;
char *token; const char delimiters[] = "?:;!,. -";
token = strtok(string, delimiters);
int i = 0;

  while(string[0] != '\0'){
    cout = 1;

    if (i > 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    for (int i = 0; token[i] >= 1 ; i++){
        if (token[i] <= 'z' && token[i] >= 'a'|| token[i] <= 'Z' && token[i] >= 'A'){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            cout = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (cout) {
        puts(token);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно же просто проверить что `token` не нулевой после строки `token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);`

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим *man 3 strtok*:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the next token,  or  NULL  if there are no more tokens.
> ```

Поэтому надо написать так:

```
token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
if (token == NULL) break;
```

Comment: А первый вызов кто проверять будет?

Comment: Вопрос был **как остановить разбор**.  А не про то, как **начать**.

Comment: Ха, и что делать, если первый уже вернул NULL?

Comment: **и что делать, если** я должен отвечать на Ваши вопросы, или на вопросы TS ?

Comment: Я вам всего лишь говорю, что ваш ответ неполон.

Comment: **ваш ответ неполон** - ну так - дополните! Кто-то мешает?

Comment: Упоротый русский SO... Это ваш ответ, у меня нет к нему доступа, а упрямство не делает чести. Посмотрите для примера как реагируют на подобные комментарии на английском SO.